# Reading text file line by line in c++ in UVA

Tags: c++, file-read

Please help me in reading the text file efficiently in c++ according to the UVA (ACM programming) standards.

If you can provide some code snippet then i will be very thankful.

Comment: Please phrase your question more specifically. What solutions did you already try? Do you want to read an arbitrary text file? Is this some kind of homework? UVA standard seems to be some coding standard, how is this related to reading a text file?

Comment: Actually i am just concerned about the file reading stuff i am not asking you about the some solution to the problem.

Comment: What i want some code that will read data from the file for example the data in the file will be like number in different lines and i have to read them. I am concerned with their efficient reading in c++. and also how to specify the file name or which file to open because when we run the program on our machine we explicitly specify the input file name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a text file par line.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream ifs("data.txt");
    string buf;

    while(ifs && getline(ifs, buf)) {
        cout << buf << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
// language: c++
```

This can be written also as following.

```
ifs >> buf;
cout << buf << endl;
// language: c++
```

Or if you want to read whole of one.

```
ifstream ifs("data.txt");
string str((istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
// language: c++
```

Comment: This isn't particularly efficient. Using memory-mapped IO would be much faster.